# Leaflet stops loading tiles

Tags: leaflet

I create a map such as

```
    L.TileLayer.CustomUrlLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
        getTileUrl: function(coords) {
            console.log("COORDINATES", coords);
            if (coords.x >= 0 && coords.x <= 20 && coords.y >= 0 && coords.y <= 20)
                 return 'img/${coords.z}/${coords.x}/${coords.y}';
            return;
        }
    });
    L.tileLayer.customUrlLayer = function(templateUrl, options) {
        return new L.TileLayer.CustomUrlLayer(templateUrl, options);
    }
    var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    }).setView([0, 0], 1);
    L.tileLayer.customUrlLayer('', {
        maxZoom: 5,
        minZoom: 1,
        tileSize: 510,
    }).addTo(map);
```

at coords.x 10, leaflet stops loading them. `console.log("COORDINATES", coords)` does not show logs then but the map exists after that; how can leaflet continue load images?
At zoom level 1 I have some tiles, at level 2 more tiles, at level 3 more tiles and so on the map gets bigger
Setting correct bounds does not work

Comment: At which zoom level you expect x and y go over 10? At zoom level 0 max x and y is 0, at zoom level 1 max is 2, at zoom 2 max is 4, at zoom 3 max is 8, at zoom 4 max is 16 and so on. See concept of tiled maps at https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

Comment: @TomazicM ok I can add multiple layers with `maxZoom = minZoom` and they increase by say 2 each time (maxZoom:0, maxZoom:2, maxZoom: 4 and so on) but the zoom does not find the nice position to zoom in anymore

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "but the zoom does not find the nice position to zoom in anymore"? Some images would help. Please edit your question and details about actual structure of your tiles (content of folder `img`).